# Does upgrading Grails from 2.4.3 to 3.2.x Improve IDE Support and Build and Startup Times

Tags: java, grails, netbeans, groovy

We have a decent size project built on Grails 2.4.3. We've experience a lot of the following issues in our development process:

- Slow build and startup (~3-5 minutes)
- Injected services using resources.groovy cannot be auto-reloaded
- Lack of NetBeans support for Jumping to Declaration
- Lack of Runtime errors shown in NetBeans

We are using IntelliJ for Grails developmet (vast improvement) but would prefer NetBeans support.

We are considering the effort to upgrade Grails App from 2.4.3 to 3.2.x in hopes that the above issues will be reduced or removed.

Besides the documented Grails change log, are there confirmed cases that an improvement has been achieved with this type of upgrade?

Comment: I'm not sure a question like this belongs here, but I'll admit I'm very curious about the answer/responses - we are running 2.4.2 (w/ Eclipse) and startup times are 5-8 minutes, combined with the non-reloading services makes for a rough time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NetBeans support will either be the same or worse for 3.x. IntelliJ IDEA is far superior.

> Slow build and startup (~3-5 minutes)

Times are typically the same or faster in 3.x

> Injected services using resources.groovy cannot be auto-reloaded

I haven't experienced this problem in 3.x

> are there confirmed cases that an improvement has been achieved with
>   this type of upgrade

Yes, I've done many of them

Comment: James Kleeh: did you experience "Injected services using sources.groovy cannot be auto-reloaded" in version older than 3.x?

Comment: @DavidGarza not that I can remember. That was a long time ago